# How to avoid being a black hat, while doing Google SERP parsing

Tags: python, parsing

So I got down-rated 3 times on my last question, and I am hoping I won't be on this one. I am trying to write a parser which parses Google's page, like so: `urllib2.urlopen("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=" + infoget)`.

Is this allowed? I can't seem to find the rules according to Google. How many requests are allowed per day/hour? I make about 40, and then I am denied.

Is this black hat? I really, absolutely am not trying to be black hat here - I am trying to write acceptable, good code.

Comment: Google doesn't like people using its web search api repeatedly. It's not their interest to support your requests if you're not going to be clicking on ads (and you might be stealing google's search results). The web search api is meant to be used for single, user defined searches from other websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview?hl=en

```
Free quota
Usage is free for all users, up to 100 queries per day.
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but I am denied after 40 requests. I want to make precisely 74 requests, and no more.

Comment: Try again tomorrow, and put a sleep time between each request (more than 2 seconds.. if time doesn't matter put it at 20s)

Comment: @AndrewAlexander, man you could use scrapy and list of proxies

Answer (score 0):

We have a Python library to fetch and parse Google Search results accessible here: https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-python

```
from lib.google_search_results import GoogleSearchResults
query = GoogleSearchResults({"q": "coffee"})
html_results = query.get_html()
```

It's working only with SerpApi.com backend right now, but feel free to extend it support more backends.

More comprehensive options:

```
query_params = {
  "q": "query",
  "google_domain": "Google Domain",
  "location": "Location Requested",
  "device": device,
  "hl": "Google UI Language",
  "gl": "Google Country",
  "safe": "Safe Search Flag",
  "num": "Number of Results",
  "start": "Pagination Offset",
  "serp_api_key": "Your SERP API Key"
}

query = GoogleSearchResults(query_params)
query.params_dict["location"] = "Portland"

html_results = query.get_html()
dictionary_results = query.get_dictionary()
dictionary_results_with_images = query.get_dictionary_with_images()
json_results = query.get_json()
json_results_with_images = query.get_json_with_images()
```

Comment: Thank you, though I left the company I was doing this for many many years ago